# Android xml pages

Tags: android, user-interface

where to add the new GUI xml pages in android project, say I have a welcome screen in res>layout>main.xml layout and when user clicks "next" button, it has to load up a new page with username and password GUI. any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

in your same layout folder

```
res>layout>login_screen.xml
```